# Is $i$ a rotation?

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Question**: Is $i$ (the imaginary number) a rotation?

---

This might be a very a loose question to ask but I can't find a better place to ask. Now a friend of mine told me this when we were discussing complex numbers, but I just can't figure out how is it a rotation? I know a complex numbers do work somewhat like vectors which deals with a lot of rotations and stuff, but I can't connect that with $i$ being a rotation. Now it can just be false in case he lied, but if it's true then please I want some explanation on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can think of multiplication by `i` as a 90-degree counterclockwise rotation in a 2d space consisting of a "real" x-axis and an "imaginary" y-axis, representing numbers that are linear combinations of real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Multiplying by i is a rotation in the complex plane 90 degrees counterclockwise.

Comment: Yes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_of_rotation#Two_dimensions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend did not really lie, but instead used a shortcut.

It's similar to mathematical properties that we learn about addition and multiplication of real numbers. For example, think about the number line.

> Addition of $1$ *is* a translation of the real number line, meaning that simultaneously adding $1$ to every point on the number line is to translate (or slide) the entire number to the right by 2 units.

Also,

> Multiplication by $2$ *is* an expansion of the real number line, meaning that simultaneously multiplying every point on the number line by $2$, has the geometrical effect of stretching the entire number line by a factor of $2$.

Now let's turn to complex numbers. I'm sure you have already learned that complex numbers $a+bi$ can be plotted in the Cartesian coordinate plane: $a+bi$ is plotted as $(a,b)$. Consider now the complex number $i = 0+1i$. What your friend said, without any shortcut, is this:

> Multiplication by $i$ *is* a rotation of the plane through an angle of $90^\circ$, meaning that simultaneously multiplying the entire complex plane by $i$ has the geometrical effect of rotating the entire plane around the origin by a positive angle of $90^\circ$.

I'm sure you can verify this for yourself with some simple computations. For example, you can easily compute $(1+2i) \cdot i = -2+i$; and you can easily verify that the angle from the vector $(1,2)$ to the vector $(-2,1)$ is $90^\circ$ in the counterclockwise direction. More generally, for any complex number $a+bi$ you can compute $(a+bi) \cdot i = -b + ai$, and you can easily verify that the angle from the vector $(a,b)$ to the vector $(-b,a)$ is $90^\circ$.

Answer (score 4):

The imaginary number $i$ is not a rotation.

The multiplication by $i$, so the map $z\mapsto z\cdot i$, can be seen as a rotation of the plane $\mathbb C$

Comment: Re: your first statement, can you think of any situations in which it is not helpful/appropriate to identify `i` with its multiplicative action on the complex numbers?

Comment: You can also add  $i$. Then it's a translation. :)

Comment: @user3716267 yeah, as Hans Engler said, when you add $1+i$ for example you're not really using the multiplicative properties of $i$

Comment: @user3716267 One can also raise a complex number to the $i$ power ($z^i$).

Comment: @HansEngler what is a translation?

Comment: Translation is like what I explained for the real line in my answer. For example, adding $i$ simultaneously to every complex number has the geometric effect of translating (or sliding) the entire complex plane upward (in the positive $y$-direction) by $1$ unit.